# how to concatenate two strings in while loop C

Tags: c, fgets

i'm using two txt files("names.txt", "fixes.txt") and need to read the words of these files line by line, and concatenate them in a new file("results.txt").
for example the names file contains this:

```
john
william
brad
```

and fixes file contains this:

```
@123
@321
@qwe
```

the code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * filename = argv[1];
    char * fixname = argv[2];
    char names[100];
    char fixes[100];
    FILE * fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    FILE * fpt = fopen(fixname, "r");
    FILE * fp = fopen("results.txt", "w");
    while (fgets ( names, sizeof(names), fptr ) != NULL)
    {
        strtok(names, "\n");
        while(fgets ( fixes, sizeof(fixes), fpt ) != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%s%s", names, fixes);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i want the results like this:

```
john@123
john@321
john@qwe
william@123
william@321
william@qwe
(and go on)
```

BUT, The result is this:

```
john@123
john@321
john@qwe
```

it won't get the other names!

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the outer while loop the inner while loop generates the EOF condition of the input file `fixname`.

So other iterations of the outer while loop skip the evaluation of the inner while loop because this condition

```
while(fgets ( fixes, sizeof(fixes), fpt ) != NULL)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is equal to false.

Use for example one outer while loop and within it use an if-statement instead of the inner while loop.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Vlad, the inner loop points to EOF post the first iteration of the outer loop.
Hence, subsequent iterations of the outer loop, skip the inner loop.

To fix this, you could bring the pointer "fpt" back to the beginning of the file after each iteration.

```
while (fgets ( names, sizeof(names), fptr ) != NULL)
{
    strtok(names, "\n");
    while(fgets ( fixes, sizeof(fixes), fpt ) != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"%s%s", names, fixes);
    }
    fseek(fpt,0,SEEK_SET);//bring fpt back to the beginning of the stream
}
```